# Error in nginx config file

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I am following the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) on Flask serving with NGINX on Digital Ocean.
After I created the following config file for NGINX in `/etc/sites-available/mysite`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

(obviously replaced domain to my domain and path to socket with my socket),
when I run `sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`, I get

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/silaeder-projects:1 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/silaeder-projects test failed
```

I double-checked that I copied the code correctly. What could go wrong?

**UPDATE:**

If I run just sudo `nginx -t`, I do not get any errors, but `sudo systemctl restart nginx` fails with:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The command `systemctl status nginx.service` returns:

```
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-11-27 11:33:49 UTC; 39s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 8485 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8475 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

`journalctl -xe` doesn't contain any time-relevant entries.

Comment: The error is legit, because you only check the part of the config. Try to check with nginx -t only (nginx.conf has the base configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nginx configuration file contains a `http` block which will include all files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. The tutorial asks you to create the file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and then link to it from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

Next it tells you to test the *complete* configuration using `sudo nginx -t` while you only test the configuration of your file. Your file however is only a small snippet of the complete nginx configuration required to make nginx work.

Make sure you create the softlink and then test without specifying a configuration file so it will test against the complete configuration file access from `/etc/nginx.conf` (or similar).

Comment: I followed the tutorial and created a lymlink; sudo nginx -t works fine: ~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: But sudo systemctl restart nginx doesn't work: sudo systemctl restart nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: And? Did you check the given commands for details?

Comment: Sure, updated the question with more data.

Comment: Finally resolved!

Answer (score 0):

The error is in a *different* file, the one that nginx read immediately prior to this one. Check the other files in sites-enabled for a missing `}`.

Comment: There I have only *default*, it looks fine.

Comment: @sooobus Keep looking.